# How to check recently installed rpms?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm

I am trying to find some recently installed `rpms` on my `redhat linux` system, Does RPM provide any way to do this?

I have tried

```
#rpm -qa
```

But it only provides installed rpms. What are the options available for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try

```
#rpm -qa --last
```

it provide a detailed summary of installed rpms with date and time stamp.
Hope it helps you.

```
#rpm -qa --last | more
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean rpm not installed but available on yum repos, you can use

```
 yum list available
```